# Is it currently possible to run Arquillian tests on Spring beans?

Tags: spring, testing, integration-testing, classnotfoundexception, jboss-arquillian

From what little experience I have of running Arquillian tests with the Arquillian Spring Framework Extension, it seems to me that things are severely broken at the moment.

I've tried running a test even simpler than the [Spring Inject](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-showcase/tree/master/spring/spring-inject) example from the arquillian showcase project (i.e. no classes, *applicationContext.xml* only, and a single test that has `assertTrue(true)` as its body).

Here are my project dependencies

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-webjars</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>adminlte</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-inject</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-service-deployer-spring-3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However this only resulted in the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver from [Module "deployment.e5488c33-14dd-41b6-8996-d616c11cbbb5.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

I've tried using the Shrinkwrap resolver to include the necessary jars, but that error still showed up.

**So tell me, is the Arquillian testing of Spring beans and components currently broken?**

P.S: The version of Spring I am using is 4.3.2.

Comment: Can you run the showcase example with Spring 4.3.2?

Comment: I have not heard this showcase example with Spring 4.3.2. Or are you suggesting that I replace the Spring version in the example with 4.3.2. Also the example is broken due to JBoss AS stalling on startup (something about JVM or JRE changes).